Including articles in a thesis document
I am trying to figure out to compile an article based thesis in LaTeX and am struggling to find a neat way to include the articles in their original journal format. All the articles were compiled in LaTeX using templates provided by the journal. Some articles are two column others are single, all have their own defined style for the title, author lists, affiliations etc. This question has previously been asked but has not received an answer: How to add Articles into an Article-based dissertation
The only way I have found is to use:
\usepackage{pdfpages}
[...]
\includepdf[pages=-]{filename.pdf}

This works but in practice has several undesirable characteristics.

Page numbering in the included pdf is for the article rather than the thesis which looks a little strange.
Hyperlinks for figures and references within the article do not work.
The article and it's sections/headings do not show up in the thesis table of contents.

It seems the combine package may have done (no longer maintained/working) what I wanted base on the answer given here: What is best practice to set up Multi-file tex documents?
I have looked at the subdocs package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subdocs but it is experimental and there is minimal documentation that I can find.
At this stage it seems there might not be a working solution for compiling multiple documents with their own style/preamble but I am hoping to get a definitive answer and/or suggested workarounds to the problems listed above for the pdfpages package.

For the page numbering, \includepdf has a pagecommand option that could be of use. \includepdf[pagecommand=\thispagestyle{mystyle}]{file.pdf}

As a supplement to Alains comment, there are similar commands such that you can run a cmd on each page and use this to say, add a white box on the page numbers from the original.

As for the hyperlinks. This is very different ball game. The hyperlink targets live in the PDF meta data, which is either ignored or wrong after the PDF gfx import. You will need to use external tools.

the hyperlinks can be reimported with the newpax package.

Regarding item 1 and 3 you might take https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720328/80551 as a suggestion.
